# Transfer Linksys router configuration to Asus router

Tags: wireless-router

I recently purchased an Asus RT-N66U wireless router to replace my old Linksys WRT160N. Since I have so many Wi-Fi enabled devices throughout my home, I don't want to bother having to set up each and every one of them again for my new router. Is it possible that I can transfer the configuration of my old one to the new one so that all of its settings get transferred? This way, I can seamlessly switch routers without having to set up all my devices again.

Comment: Probably not since it's differnet brands. But using the same SSID, encryption method and PW should make it work anyway?

Comment: @jtheman Someone said to me about creating a "manifest" on the old router and then loading it on the new one. How does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that, since the routers are of different brands, you cannot transfer the configuration to the other router. Most of the time, you can simply make sure the SSID, encryption type, and password are the same. On the other hand, if you changed advanced settings on the old router (like port forwarding), you will need to go through every page of the old router UI where you made changes and configure the settings on the new one. If the routers were of the same brand or kind, you could simply backup the configuration to a local file on your computer, then load it on the new one.